# Can't get Uri with getTag

Tags: android

I am trying to build a music player for Android OS. I am dynamically making a listView and it sets tags with the Uri, so that the Uris can later be retreived with getTag. However, this doesn't work. It gives an ClassCastException at the getTag line. Here is my code:

SongList.java :

```
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class SongList extends Fragment {

        private ArrayList<Song> songList;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_list, container, false);

            //retrieve list view
            ListView songView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            //instantiate list
            songList = new ArrayList<>();

            getSongList();

            Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
                public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                    return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
                }
            });

            final SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter( getActivity(), songList);
            songView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

            songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    setSong(view);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        void getSongList() {
            //retrieve song info
            ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

            //iterate through music
            if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
                //get columns
                int idColumn                = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int titleColumn             = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int artistColumn            = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int albumColumn             = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                int albumIdColumn           = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
                int UriColumn               = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                //add songs to list
                do {
                    long thisId         = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle    = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist   = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    String thisAlbum    = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
                    long thisAlbumId    = musicCursor.getLong(albumIdColumn);
                    Uri thisUri         = Uri.parse( musicCursor.getString( UriColumn ) );

                    songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum, thisAlbumId, thisUri));
                }
                while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        public void setSong(View view) {
            if ( MainActivity.isCreatedCheck() ){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Uri songUri = (Uri) view.getTag();
                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), songUri);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

SongAdapter.java:


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //song list and layout
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;

    //constructor
    public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs=theSongs;
        songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //map to song layout
        RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout) songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, parent, false);

        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView               = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.titleListTextView);
        TextView artistView             = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.artistListTextView);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout   = (RelativeLayout)songLay.findViewById(R.id.layoutSelector);

        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);

        //get title and artist strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());

        relativeLayout.setTag( currSong.getURI() );

        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }

}
```

song_list_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_200"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_song_border"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/song_height"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSelector">

        <com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:src="@drawable/album_default"
            android:id="@+id/albumListImageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/song_album_metrics"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/song_album_metrics"
            app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
            app:riv_oval="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/song_image_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/song_title_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/titleListTextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/song_title"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/song_title_margin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/artistListTextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/song_artist"
            android:textSize="@dimen/song_artist_text_size"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/song_title_margin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting tag to same view twice; first a `Uri` and then an integer. Because of this setting `Uri` as tag is overridden by the integer thus giving ClassCastException. If see carefully then `songLay` and `relativeLayout` represents same view.

Remove following line and it would work.

```
songLay.setTag(position);
```

Comment: You are right about the exception, however, it still doesn't work. I changed the code to your answer and now it gives the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: 

java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
            at com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength.SongList.setSong(SongList.java:90)
            at com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength.SongList$2.onItemClick(SongList.java:48)

and some more code

Comment: Thank you, that line was the problem. Thank you very much.